# SUM interval of rows even if error

Tags: excel

i'm trying to sum values but when a cell as an error, id like that to count as a 0, and continue adding.

the values in the cells are 15:60, or 8:00, "h:mm"

i've tried this:
{=SUM(IF(ISERROR(A1:A7);0;A1:A7))}

but it gives me a weird value

example:

15:00

06:00

gives me 0,875?

i just want it to add, 15:30 + 15:30, should give 31:00

thx in advance!
[SOLVED] change the cell type to TIME 37:30:55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

21/24 = 0.875

The result is 21:00 but in float number, the normal way for Excel to store time.
The same with date times, they are also stored that way.
Integer (whole numbers) as the number of days since 1/1/1900 and the fraction as the time.
Most likely all you need to do is to change the format of the cell to time and it will be displayed correct.

Comment: thank you, but actually what i need it for it to just add the time, if i have 10:00 + 10:00 + 10:00 it gives me 30:00

Comment: but if it is 10:30 + 10:30, i want it to be 21:00

Comment: Ok... and what does Excel sum it to? If the cell properties are correct that is.

Comment: he doesnt accept more than 23:59, example, 15:30 + 15:30 gives 07:00

Comment: use format as time type of `37:30:55` or custom type `[h]:mm:ss`

Comment: I'm using Excel online, and doing the SHIFT + CTRL + ENTER to pass it to array doesn't work :( help?